# How can i Create a Static component in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, thread-safety

am doing some app that has a lots of forms and some components have to access some componets from another form ....when i make my richtextbox public and try to access it from somewhere else it says thread safe error bla bla ...so i made that text box static so that there would be only object that belong to the class and i can access it like this.

```
Form1.richTextBox.Text
```

and this works fine but the problem is every time i add a new component to the winform my static object become non static and all my direct access to the objects becomes error.
 my question is how can i make visual studio to stop modifying my code(design code) ? or safely access objects from other form without circular dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment "try to access it from somewhere else it says thread safe error"
I believe the issue is a cross thread operation. Is that "somewhere else" executing on a background/worker thread? ie. NOT the thread on which your richtextbox was instantiated.
If so, you MUST test the InvokeRequired property.
From MSDN:
"Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a different thread than the one the control was created on."

BTW: Even though you see a C# object (richtextbox), it is merely a facade over a Windows Handle. So, Visual Studio's behavior is correct. A control can have ONLY one parent(ie the Window) If you 'think' you need a static richtextbox then you should rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create some static element like String myStatic and access to this element from other form. In place where you need update this element use some method like

```
void UpdateMyStatic() {
myStatic = richTextBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: ya that was a good idea but am writing to a textbox not reading. plus the method should have to be static to use a static variable . so when u make mystatic text static it forces u to make richTextBox too